# Define specific color for Numpy array matrix in matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have the the following np.array with the shape of (2766, 2432):

```
np.array([[0.0264, 0.0428, 0.0414, ..., 0.2092, 0.2092, 0.2169],
          [0.0342, 0.0408, 0.0386, ..., 0.226 , 0.226 , 0.2121],
          [0.0354, 0.0367, 0.0445, ..., 0.2649, 0.2649, 0.2105],
          ...,
          [0.3104, 0.3104, 0.3191, ..., 0.3835, 0.3808, 0.4052],
          [0.2971, 0.2971, 0.3119, ..., 0.3677, 0.3701, 0.3924],
          [0.2938, 0.3198, 0.3198, ..., 0.3481, 0.3701, 0.3783]],
          dtype=float32)
```

right now in order to display it I do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.matshow(nir)
```

My question is if I can define threshold to color the image as I want.

For example:

If the value of pixel is between  0-0.3 the color will be blue , if the value is between 0.3-0.6 will be orange, without using `cmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to create a custom `cmap` and pass it to `matshow`. That said, per your request, you can try:

```
# test data
img = np.array([[0.0,0.5, 0.6],[0.1, 0.4,0.1]])

# color mapping
colors = np.zeros(img.shape + (3,))

colors[(0<img) & (img<=0.3)] = (0, 0, 1)     # blue 
colors[(.3<img) & (img<=.6)] = (1, .647,0)   # orange 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.matshow(colors)
```

Output:

[image]